# Menu icon does not shown in my samsung galaxy tablet

Tags: android, android-layout

I am tring to execute an application with a menu in my galaxy tablet. here is the code for creating the menu:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
return true;
}
```

and here is the menu layout:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_about"
        android:title="@string/menu_about"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"
    />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_limt_time_rocord"
        android:title="@string/menu_limt_time_rocord"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_timer"
    />
</menu>
```

While in my phone the menu is being display by pressing the "ordinary" menu button, in my galaxy tablet the menu button is not displayed at all and I am not able to open the menu at all.

**how do I display a menu button in my tablet?**

Thanks in advance

Kobi

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You menus and all are correct. DO one thing, remove targetSDKVersion from the manifest file and use only `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />`.

I think this is the only problem. Now on 3.0 onward you can see the menu buttons.

Comment: i did that too but nothing changed. The menu seems now still not showing on my tablet android 4.x @Anupam

Comment: I am having the same problem on Samsung Galaxy Tab 4 os 4.4.2. Menu shows fine on many other targets, I have <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" /> and no targetSDKVersion, but menu does not display, even if I create it in onCreateOptionsMenu.

Comment: My Samsung Galaxy on 4.2.2 also has the same problem and it can't be resolved by changing targetversion.

Answer (score 0):

As per the Documentation described [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#options-menu) In android Android 3.x  function **onCreateOptionsMenu()** is called when the activity starts to populate ActionBar, not when user touches the Menu button for the first time