# Menu Button does not show in Tablet

Tags: android, android-menu

I have involved with Menu not displaying problem. Menu is displaying in all android device which has menu button. But this is not displaying in Tablet. i tryied also in Galaxy.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

and my menu code:-

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
        {
            switch (item.getItemId())
            { 
            case R.id.profile:

                Intent iu = new Intent(userLists.this, uploadImage.class);
                startActivity(iu);
                return true;

            case R.id.chatsetting:
                Intent cs = new Intent(userLists.this, chatsetting.class);
                startActivity(cs);
                return true;

                  default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
            }
        }    

       @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
        {
            MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
            menuInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu, menu);

            return true;

        }
```

please any one solve this query!
Thank You!

Comment: Remove  `android:targetSdkVersion="16"` 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063754/menu-icon-does-not-shown-in-my-samsung-galaxy-tablet

Comment: i saw a point. please see my updated!

Answer (score 0):

Well i solved,

I removed my android:theme="@style/AppTheme" from androidManifest.xml . and show menu button.
but now time all screeen is going to Black background colour. I hate to black theme.

So i need to create my own theme.

Menu button was there. but theme was not displaying it.
Is there way so menu will display without remove default theme.

I solved by change the title color.

Answer (score 0):

Change the manifest file: you should change targetSdkVersion to <= 10.
Like this:

```
<uses-sdk 
    android:minSdkVersion="8" 
    android:targetSdkVersion="9"/>
```